# Windows Server 2008 64-bit RAM going somewhere

Tags: windows-server-2008, memory

I am looking after a server that has 6GB of RAM. There is a JAVA binary running that is using 1.8GB RAM, but nothing else is using anything near that, but I am seeing a constant 85%+ usage of physical memory.

The other processes don't add up to the difference so where else can I see what is using the memory?

I've never seen this before...

**UPDATE 1:**
During my research I have discovered that SQL server can use more memory than it shows it is using in Task Manager. My box is running MySQL so I am wondering if a similar thing happens here?

Comment: Have you tried the sysinternals process explorer?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Is the 85% consumed memory *active* memory or is the majority of it buffers?

Comment: and to add to @MDMarra - what tool(s) are you using to come to this conclusion?

Comment: I'm using Process Explorer and that shows Physical Usage as 85%. Where do I see it as active or buffered?

Comment: Generally. using as much memory as possible to buffer and speed stuff up is A Good Thing (TM), which Windows likes to do when there is free memory wasting money just sitting there...

Answer (score 2):

Windows has a built-in tool for analysing memory usage called **Resource Monitor**, you can start it by executing `resmon.exe`. By navigating to the `Memory` tab you'll get a graphical representation of your memory usage as well as process-specific data.

If you require even more information there is a Microsoft Sysinternals utility called `RAMMap` - it will give you a lot more information on both total and process usages. You can download it from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229).